# How to extract name and phone number from address

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to separate name, city, state, zip and phone from full address. I managed to separate zip using the below code.

```
 String input = richTextBox1.Text;

        Regex regex = new Regex(@"(\d{6})",
            RegexOptions.Compiled |
            RegexOptions.CultureInvariant);

        Match match = regex.Match(input);

        if (match.Success)
            textBox2.Text = match.Groups[1].Value;
```

No. of digits in zip code doesn't change, so it is fairly simple for me. But for phone number the no. of digits changes and some times space comes in between like the example below. I am totally confused on how to extract this type of phone numbers.

I tried the below code for phone number and ".star\s.star" to extract name but it is not working.

```
        Regex regex1 = new Regex(@"\b\d{3}\s\d{2}\s\d{6}",
            RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.CultureInvariant);

        Match match1 = regex1.Match(input);

        if (match1.Success)
            textBox3.Text = match1.Groups[1].Value;

        else
        {
            Regex regex2 = new Regex(@"\b\d{4}\s\d{3}\s\d{4}",
            RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.CultureInvariant);

            Match match2 = regex2.Match(input);

            if (match2.Success)
                textBox3.Text = match2.Groups[1].Value;
        }
```

Sample Address:

```
H.
Mithras Developers
Tiruchendur Road, VM Chathiram PO, Radhapur, Tirunelveli, TN 628809 ‎
097 43 838122 ‎
```

EDIT---

I finally figured the answer for phone.

```
 @"(\d{3}\ \d{2}\ \d{6})", @"(\d{4}\ \d{3}\ \d{4})"
```

Please help me with extracting city and state. I am currently working on extracting the Name. I will update this post if I find the answer myself.

EDIT---

I found the way to extract the Name.

```
@"^(.*)", selecting the first line of the address.
```

The question is pretty much over.

Comment: is the phone number always in the last line of the address?

Comment: Yes also it is either in the form xxx xx xxxxxx or xxxx xxx xxxx, Also is there a way to extract next line followed by A-Z\. (To extract Name). Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Way to extract the Name.

```
@"^(.*)", selecting the first line of the address.
```

Way to extract the phone.

```
@"(\d{3}\ \d{2}\ \d{6})", @"(\d{4}\ \d{3}\ \d{4})"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This...

```
    (\w+\s*\w+)\s+([\w\s]+),\s+([\w\s]+),\s+([\w\s]+),\s+([\w\s]+),\s*(\w{2}\s*\d+)\s*([\d\s]{9,13})
```